# EditText Events in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am pretty new to Android world. I have created multiple EditTexts(1,2,..). I want to check if EditText1 is empty, while moving the focus to EditText2. I used OnFocusedChangeListener, but its not helping. May be its too simple, but could not get it through googling.

Below is my xml for EditText boxes:

```
  <EditText 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/Text1" 
  />
 <EditText 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:id="@+id/Text2" 
 />
```

And, here's my java:

```
Edittext E1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Text1); 
EditText E2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Text2);
```

Now, what I would like to do is, Check null for E1 and E2. While jumping from E1 to E2 in the UI, check if E1 is null and disable, if it is.

Thank you,
PiKey.

Comment: copy paste the code that you are trying with layout xml.

Comment: Please check the edits, I have made.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

xml :

```
<EditText 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/Text1" 
      <requestFocus />
  />

 <EditText 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:id="@+id/Text2" 
      <requestFocus />
 />
```

And for the code

```
Edittext E1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Text1); 
EditText E2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Text2); 
if (E1.getText().toString().compareTo("") == 0){
     E2.requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it from addTextChangedListener.